# WooCommerce - Price was converted twice on cart/checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, converters

The currency conversion plugin I use for my quote request website works great until I redirect from an email to the Cart page. I am using GBP as the base currency and USD, EUR, CAD, AED as the other currencies.

If I make a request in USD (or any other), the price in the email gets converted a second time when I am redirected to the cart page, which distorts the value a customer receives. I believe it assumes the price coming from the email is GBP and thus does a second conversion, which is not needed.

I found a supposed fix for this but it was for a single currency.

```
//We are reversing the price of product to USD in cart page, because the rate is applied again there
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'fix_currency_conversion');
function fix_currency_conversion($cart_object){
            global $WOOCS;
            $cur_currency = $WOOCS->current_currency;
            $currencies = $WOOCS->get_currencies();
            $conversion_rate = $currencies[$WOOCS->current_currency]['rate'];
            if($cur_currency == 'HKD'){
                foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->price = $cart_item['data']->price / $conversion_rate;
                }
            }
}
```

Can you please suggest how I might be able to add more currencies? I already tried this but my php is not so strong. I added this line in the place of the if statement above:

```
// Do not convert these currencies
$keep_rate = array( 'NGN', 'USD', 'CAD', 'EUR', 'AED' );

// Don’t convert currencies when it's one of these rates
if ( has_term( $keep_rate, 'currencies', $WOOCS->get_currencies() ) ) {
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->price = $cart_item['data']->price / $conversion_rate;
                }
}
```

Comment: hello WP geniuses, please i need your help